# Error al actualizar fila Jtable edita todas las filas en MySQL Java

Tags: java, netbeans

tengo el siguiente error: Escaneo los datos que tengo el DB y me arroja los resultados en la tabla**(tablaResultados)** y cuando quiero editar una fila, se me cargan los datos en los **textField** correspondientes para que pueda editarlos, y cuando doy guardar cambios en el botón Actualizar. Me actualiza el valor que quiero en todas las filas de la tabla.
Para ser mas simple el error, les muestro una imagen para que visualicen el error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la parte donde configuro la acción de **seleccionar la tabla**:

```
    private void tablaResultadosMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                             
    int fila=this.tablaResultados.getSelectedRow();//CREO FILA PARA LA SELECCION DE LA TABLA Y ROW
    this.tfNombre.setText(this.tablaResultados.getValueAt(fila,1).toString());
    this.tfApellido.setText(this.tablaResultados.getValueAt(fila,2).toString());
    this.tfCel.setText(this.tablaResultados.getValueAt(fila,3).toString());
    this.tfDni.setText(this.tablaResultados.getValueAt(fila,6).toString());
    this.tfCiudad.setText(this.tablaResultados.getValueAt(fila,5).toString());
    this.tfDomicilio.setText(this.tablaResultados.getValueAt(fila,4).toString());
    this.tfNotas.setText(this.tablaResultados.getValueAt(fila,7).toString());
    //FIN DE LA SECCION
}
```

Esta es la acción del botón **Actualizar:**

```
    private void botonActualizarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
if(tablaResultados.getSelectedRowCount()==1){
    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/database", "user", "pass");
        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("UPDATE clientes SET Nombre='"+tfNombre.getText()+"',Apellido='"+tfApellido.getText()+"',Cel='"+tfCel.getText()+"',Domicilio='"+tfDomicilio.getText()+"',Ciudad='"+tfCiudad.getText()+"',Dni='"+tfDni.getText()+"',Notas='"+tfNotas.getText()+"'");
        int respuesta=ps.executeUpdate();
        if (respuesta>0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Datos del cliente se han"+"\n"+"actualizado correctamente");
            limpiar();
        }
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error:");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error: 2"+"\n"+e);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: ¡Un _update_ sin un _where_!

Comment: Gracias @padaleiana ya pude solucionarlo como indicaste pero otro usuario me dio la solución.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te comenta padaleina tienes que poner en tu query un WHERE, debido a que cuando se hace un UPDATE sin un WHERE se afectan todas las filas por igual.

```
 private void botonActualizarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
if(tablaResultados.getSelectedRowCount()==1){
    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/database", "user", "pass");
        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("UPDATE clientes SET Nombre='"+tfNombre.getText()+"',Apellido='"+tfApellido.getText()+"',Cel='"+tfCel.getText()+"',Domicilio='"+tfDomicilio.getText()+"',Ciudad='"+tfCiudad.getText()+"',Dni='"+tfDni.getText()+"',Notas='"+tfNotas.getText()+"' " + "WHERE id =" + user.id);
        int respuesta=ps.executeUpdate();
        if (respuesta>0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Datos del cliente se han"+"\n"+"actualizado correctamente");
            limpiar();
        }
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error:");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error: 2"+"\n"+e);
    }
}
}
```

Saludos...

Comment: Muchas gracias, solucione el error con tu ayuda.